# How to create a window such that while press and hold the mouse pointer in window client area we can move the window?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

How we can move the window by pressing and holding the mouse in window client area.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1361132/894321

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`QWidget::move()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#pos-prop) to move the window around. You detect when the user presses (with [`mousePressEvent()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent)) and holds (with [`mouseMoveEvent()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent)) the mouse and use those delta values to move the top-left corner os the window accordingly.

Holding the mouse means to set a flag in `mousePressEvent()`and to check that the flag is set in `mouseMoveEvent()`. Call `globalPos()` on the `QMouseEvent` passed to get the position of the cursor and save it so that you know the last cursor position between calls to `mouseMoveEvent()`. Then you calculate the difference between the last position and the current position and move the window the delta distance.

As an example add these to your window class:

```
class Window : public QWidget {

// ..

protected:
  void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
  void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);  
  void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);                                          

private:
  bool down;
  QPoint lastPos;
};
```

And one way to implement them would be:

```
void Window::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
  if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
    down = true;
    lastPos = event->globalPos();  
  }

  QWidget::mousePressEvent(event);  
}

void Window::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
  down = false;  
  QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(event);  
}

void Window::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
  if (down) {
    QPoint curPos = event->globalPos();
    if (curPos != lastPos) {
      QPoint diff = (lastPos - curPos);
      move(pos() - diff);
      lastPos = curPos;
    }
  }

  QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

Now left clicking and holding in the client area will move the window around.

Comment: You don't need `QCursor::pos()`, use the `QMouseEvent::globalPos()` instead, it's passed in to the mouse event handlers already.

Comment: I did not clear about this. Actually my question was by holding the window in its title bar we can move the window to any place in desktop just like this  how we can achieve this by holding it in window client area.Can we achieve this by what you are saying?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <windows.h>

void LeftClick ( );

int main(){
    Sleep(3000);

    LeftClick(); //holds 5 sec.
}



void LeftClick ( )
{  
  INPUT    Input={0};
  // left down 
  Input.type      = INPUT_MOUSE;
  Input.mi.dwFlags  = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
  ::SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(INPUT));

  // left up
  Sleep(5000);   //this line is delaying key up ******
  ::ZeroMemory(&Input,sizeof(INPUT));
  Input.type      = INPUT_MOUSE;
  Input.mi.dwFlags  = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
  ::SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(INPUT));
}
```