# Remove top bar of gui in qt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-designer

In either qt designer (preferably) or python, is there a way to remove the standard windows top bar and replace it with my own, or at least format it.  This is similar to how the new versions of photoshop, maya, 3ds max, chrome etc.. look.

I found these two articles but besides for being in C++, and I need to work in python, they were never resolved.

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/3331/
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/3847/

What I did get from it is the FramelessWindowHint which does what I want, but as they mention in the article, it eliminates much of windows functionality, such as resizing.  Is there a way to reintroduce the corner drag and resizing/closing options manually?

To be more specific, I already have the program designed in qt designer and used pyuic4 to make my python file.  This is my main function that loads the gui:

```
global globalMoAnWindow
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create('plastique'))
globalMoAnWindow = MoAnWin()
globalMoAnWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
globalMoAnWindow.showMaximized()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

For anyone looking to use python and drag the widget, i found this code:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
        self.dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()
        event.accept()

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
        self.move(event.globalPos() - self.dragPosition)
        event.accept()
```

That I put in my Class that deals with the main window

Comment: You can remove system top bar (with FramelessWindowHint) and create your top bar as a widget with your buttons, graphics etc. with closing button you just give QApplication::close, with resizing it's a little more complicated ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `QSizeGrip` to add resize controls to your window. They act exactly like system behavior. You should create a layout and put QSizeGrip to each corner of your window.

```
widget = QWidget()
widget.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
layout = QGridLayout(widget)
layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
sizeGrip1 = QSizeGrip(widget)
sizeGrip2 = QSizeGrip(widget)
sizeGrip3 = QSizeGrip(widget)
sizeGrip4 = QSizeGrip(widget)
layout.addWidget(sizeGrip1, 0, 0)
layout.addWidget(sizeGrip2, 0, 2)
layout.addWidget(sizeGrip3, 2, 2)
layout.addWidget(sizeGrip4, 2, 0)
label = QLabel("Contents")
layout.addWidget(label, 1, 1)

widget.show()
```

Variation for QMainWindow:

```
window = QMainWindow()
widget = QWidget()
window.setCentralWidget(widget)
window.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
layout = QGridLayout(widget)
#...
window.show()
```

Implementing close button is simple. Just add a QPushButton or QToolButton to your layout and call `QWidget::close` in its onclick handler.

Dragging is more complicated as there is no standard widget to do this. A solution is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361195/344347).

Comment: Thanks, but I am making my window in qt designer and pyuic4, so when I try to add a layout it says my window already has a layout.  I am able to set the window frame off by doing globalWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint) but I cant figure out how to add the widgets in your explanation

Comment: But your link to the drag worked well for me.  I found a python example and it seemed pretty easy:    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.dragPosition = event.globalPos() - self.frameGeometry().topLeft()
            event.accept()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self.dragPosition)
            event.accept()

Comment: I've added en example for QMainWindow. You need to deal with window's central widget.

Comment: Sorry maybe i didnt explain it well, I already have a gui with a main window that was made in qt designer and a separate file that has my widgets already setup, so when i try to set a widget I get the error that my layout already has a widget.  I edited my question to show how I am calling it

Comment: If you already have a window with a layout, you obviously don't need to add another widget and another layout. Just add `QSizeGrip` widgets to existing layout.

Comment: Well I should have checked this before but even the example you give doesnt work for me, if it resizes to the right, there is space on the left side.  Besides that, adding the size grip on the central widget of the window doesnt work either